Group values into single column instead of multiple columns
I have dataset of multiple columns with group variables. I want group values into single column
I have dataset like this



VAR1
VAR2
SCORE




MALE
LOC1
20


MALE
LOC2
30


MALE
LOC3
40


FEMALE
LOC4
50


FEMALE
LOC5
60


FEMALE
LOC6
70



I want the output should be like



VAR1
SCORE




MALE



LOC1
20


LOC2
30


LOC3
40


FEMALE



LOC4
50


LOC5
60


LOC6
70




Are you trying to format your data into a table? If so, packages like reactable have built-in functions for grouping and aggregation that produce this type of result. Take a look.


dplyr approach with reframe()

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  reframe(VAR1 = c(VAR1[1], VAR2),
          SCORE = c(NA, SCORE),
          .by = VAR1)

#     VAR1 SCORE
# 1   MALE    NA
# 2   LOC1    20
# 3   LOC2    30
# 4   LOC3    40
# 5 FEMALE    NA
# 6   LOC4    50
# 7   LOC5    60
# 8   LOC6    70



base approach with by()

by(df, df$VAR1, \(x) {
  with(x, data.frame(VAR1 = c(VAR1[1], VAR2), SCORE = c(NA, SCORE)))
}) |> unname() |> do.call(what = rbind)


Thankyou so much its working. But using reframe getting error message as could not find reframe function even though dplyr package is installed. Using second method by( ) it is working.

@VAMSIKRISHNAGundabattuni reframe is added to dplyr after the version 1.1.0. I think your package is outdated. Try to re-install it with install.packages("dplyr") and use my code again.

Using split and rbind
EDIT, usable with any number of columns
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$VAR1), \(x) 
  rbind(c(x[1,1], as.list(rep(NA, length(x)-2))), x[,2:ncol(df)]))) |> 
    `rownames<-`(NULL)
    VAR2 SCORE
1 FEMALE    NA
2   LOC4    50
3   LOC5    60
4   LOC6    70
5   MALE    NA
6   LOC1    20
7   LOC2    30
8   LOC3    40


Thanks for your response. This code is working, but when there are 5 columns, getting error msg as subscripts out of bound. I have mentioned it as x[,2:5].Please suggest me where it is going wrong.

See edit, made some changes to enable any number of columns. length(x)-2 is the number of NAs (5 - 2 in case of 5 initial columns).

It worked.Thanks a lot. Is it possible to add a blank row after each group like after Female group. I have used-head(do.call(rbind, by(df, df$"VAR2", rbind, "")), -1 ).But it is creating blank after every variable. Thanks for your response.

Try do.call(rbind, rbind(lapply(split(df, df$VAR1), \(x) rbind(c(x[1,1], as.list(rep(NA, length(x)-2))), x[,2:ncol(df)])), "")) |> rownames<-(NULL)

This is perfect.. thank you so much for your prompt responses.
